Inital char pointer with a string
How is it possible to initialize a pointer without assigning memory to it?!
I saw code like this.  I tried the following example and I see that it works but according to my knowledge it should not work.  How is it possible to initialize a pointer without assigning memory to it?!
Code for example:
typedef struct{
    char* c;
    int b;
}st;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    st a={
        (char*)"qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxccvbm",
        3
    }; 
     std::cout<<a.c<<a.b<<std::endl;

It prints the wole string and the right number.
How?

Wherever you found this code don't go back.  There is a lot wrong with it.  If you want to learn C++, get yourself a good C++ book

"Assigning memory to a pointer" is not a very well defined term. There is memory assigned for the string literal "qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxccvbm".

String literals: Where do they go?

it should not work why shouldn't it work?

I'm not sure how a.c relates to a pointer. That's just an ordinary field in an ordinary object, local to main. Of course a.c can hold 3.

You shouldn't do this learn about std::string and probably some more C++ from a good source, e.g. learncpp.com. While it is useful to know how (raw) pointers work, current C++ doesn't use them as much as most teachers would like you to believe. (There are iterators, containers and std::unique_ptr now)

You should print a separator between a.c and a.b.  Otherwise they will be printed next to each other and sometimes difficult to see where one ends and the other starts.

Your assumption is just flawed. The following is perfectly legal:
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   const char* p0 = "asd"; // Memory is allocated for "asd", p0 points to that
   const char* p1 = p0; // Points to same memory
   auto p2 = p1; // Also points to the same memory
   std::cout << p2; // Prints "asd"

   int a = 3;
   const int* q0 = &a; // Points to the memory of a
   const int* q1 = q0; // Also points to a
   auto q2 = q1; // Also points to a
   std::cout << *q2; // Prints 3

}

Pointers don't have to point to unique allocations.

You might want to add specifically that string literals are special and they are actually static arrays with storage that the compiler generates.

@NathanOliver: I added the int a=3 case explicitly to show it's actually not that special, at least not for the purpose of this question. There's a pre-existing object somewhere, so you can have a pointer to it. You only need to allocate memory if you want a pointer to a new object.

int a = 3, IMHO is a lot different than const char * foo = "blah" considering you cant to int * foo = 3.  It seems to me like that is where the OP's confusion is comming from.

Consider static constexpr std::string_view str1{"ads"}; for string literals. In general when using pointers... they should not be the first choice (anymore)
